# magento Multi store sitemap not working

Tags: sitemap, magento-1.7

I have two different store one singel magento installation.

The multi store work fine but sitemap not working fine.

If I create sitemap for second store the first store(installed magento store) sitemap is rewrite.

What I do ?
Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

i generate the sitemap and copy the sitemap.xml file to my second store.

the creation time one link will have that place i replace.